# Sending javamail using Office365 mail template

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, office365, office365api, email-templates

I want to send mail from java application using javamail through Office 365, which I am able to do.

Now my requirement is that I need to send mail using some template which is already created in Office 365 account.

Moreover I need to add some customized data on the mail template(like mail merge), which I am not able to do.

Can we send mail through javamail using some already created mail template? If so please help me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: In what form is the mail template?  Is it an email message?  Is it just text with fields to fill in for the message body?  Is it XML?